# Is there a way to ignore SIGCHLD in Boost testing framework using macro definitions?

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I have such a problem: my C++ code needs to start and then kill child process. All is ok, but when i try to write tests for it using Boost.Test tests fail with

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "test_sync": child was killed; pid: 7787; uid: 1000; exit value: 9
```

This is because Boost treats killing of child as failure. It can be solved by starting test with `--catch_system_errors=no` command line option, but i do not like this solution, as anything I want is just to ignore SIGCHLD. More, i want to do it without passing any command line options, in compile time. A macro definition would be ok, but

```
BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_SIGCHLD
```

does not work for me. It just has no effect.

I'm using boost-1.53.0.

Comment: Did you define BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_SIGCHLD at the very top of your file?

Comment: Comments here suggest BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_SIGCHLD must be defined during the compilation of the Boost test library itself: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/52991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Zwinck has answered my question in comments: [Comments here suggest BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_SIGCHLD must be defined during the compilation of the Boost test library itself](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/52991)

It seems like there is no way to achieve it during application compilation.